# How can I find another Mongoose document (by ID) from a document's instance method?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My model saves the ID of its "parent" (in a tree structure). In one of its instance methods, I want to edit the parent. Is there a way I can look it up via this ID? `Model.findById` doesn't work, obviously. Do I have access to this function in some other way?

Comment: Can you edit your question to provide a more complete example?  It's not obvious to me why `Model.findById` won't work.

Comment: Because it's an instance method. It's defined inside the model itself, like `RegionSchema.methods.addUpdateData = function(contents, callback)`. I actually found a slightly hacky solution in GitHub issues. I'll answer my own question with that. Hopefully they add a cleaner way to do this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can access the doc's model in an instance method via `this.constructor`; so you can to do this as:

```
RegionSchema.methods.addUpdateData = function(contents, callback) {
    this.constructor.findById(this.parentId, function(err, doc) { ... });
}
```

Comment: Oh this is nice. I came across this but couldn't get it to work because I was calling it on `this` in some callback instead of an alias.

Answer (score 0):

According to [this GitHub issue](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/772#issue-3631363), the way to access `find` and related methods through instance methods is `this.db.model('Car').findById`, where `'Car'` should be replaced by the model name, obviously.

It's a bit redundant and hacky, and I am still looking for a cleaner solution for this.